# selenium rc - firefox keeps on asking for proxy?

Tags: selenium

i have created firefox template and started selenium server from command line giving -firefoxProfileTemplate "path to the profile" but still it asks for proxy?

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you changed the lan settings for your new FF profile to use the proxy?
2. When the tests open the FF browser, check the proxy settings manually and see if its there? If not, then Selenium might still be NOT using the correct profile.

Comment: thanks for your response. i have checked the proxy setting in firefox it has proxy setting what i have given!,but still askes for proxy? also checked the settings it is correct!

Comment: Is it asking for a username/pwd to connect to proxy server? Or just showing cannot access internet?

Comment: is it hitting basic authentication?

Comment: Did you try this?java -jar selenium-server.jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password

Comment: @ AJ77- yes i tried with no use!    @AutomatedTester- means? i didn't get you.